# Minimal $k$ for which $n^k$ outgrows $n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to undertand the asymptotic behavior of $n^k$ versus $n!$. What is the minimal $k$ so that $n!$ dominates?

EDIT: Asked intended question wrong. For the question I meant to ask, see

[Minimal $c$ for which $n^{cn}$ outgrows $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688410/minimal-c-for-which-ncn-outgrows-n)

Comment: For all $k\in\mathbb N$ we have $\frac{n^k}{n!}\to 0$. Note that the exponent in $n^{n/2}$ is not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you denote:
$$
a_n(k)=\frac{n^k}{n!},\ a_0=0,\ k>1;
$$
You have:
$$
a_1=1, a_2=\frac{2^k}{2}=2^{k-1}, a_3=\frac{3^k}{3\cdot2}=\frac{3^{k-1}}{2}, \dots
$$
For small $n$, it seems that the numerator can prevails, at least for large $k$, but if we analyse:
$$
\lim_{n,\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n,\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n},
$$
The first factor tends to $1$, whilst the second factors leads the limit to $0$, hence, the sequence is convergent.

It means that the denominator, for every $k>1$, increases more rapidly than the denominator. Finally, $n!$ always outgrows $n^k$, for $k>1$, and for $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You want the smallest $k$ such that $n^k > n!$ for some large $n$.

Taking the log on both sides you get :
$$k\log n > \log n! \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad k > \frac{\log n!}{\log n}$$
So the smallest $k\in \mathbb N$ is the smallest integer satisfying the above.

The right hand side can be expressed in various ways such as :

- $\dfrac{\log\big(\Gamma(n+1)\big)}{\log n}$
- $\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\log i}{\log n}$

There are other ways to express them. I suggest you have a look at how [the right hand side behaves](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28n!%29/log%28n%29) so that it gives you an idea of how the smallest $k$ will vary as a function of $n$. However the function is increasing to infinity so you can't have one $k$ for all $n$.

For the $k$ you find, $n^k$ will not outgrow $n!$ as $n\to \infty$ but you will have : 
$$m^k > m! \quad \forall \, m \le n$$

Answer (score 0):

By Stirling we have $$ n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt {2\pi n}$$
hence 
$$ \frac{n!}{n^{cn}}\sim \left(\frac{n^{1-c}}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}.$$
If $c<1$, the parentheses grows $>1$ and hence $\frac{n!}{n^{cn}}\to\infty$.
On the other hand, for $c=1$, we clearly have $\frac{n!}{n^n}\to 0$