# Minimal $c$ for which $n^{cn}$ outgrows $n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider $n^{cn}$ versus $n!$. For $c=1$, $n^n$ clearly dominates $n!$. What is the behavior for $c=1/2$? I seem to remember that $n!$ dominates $n^{n/2}$. If this is true, what is the minimal $c$ for which $n^{cn}$ outgrows $n!$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) tells us that as $n\to\infty$,
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.
$$
In particular,
$$
\frac{n!}{n^{cn}}\sim\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n^{cn}}\cdot\frac{n^n}{e^n}=\frac{n^{(1-c)n+\frac{1}{2}}}{e^n}.
$$
If $1-c>0$, then the numerator will (eventually) overpower the denominator here, and make this tend to $\infty$. When $1-c=0$, this definitely tends to $0$.  And when $1-c<0$, it also definitely tends to $0$.

So, overall: $c=1$ **is** the minimal $c$ for which $n^{cn}$ "outgrows" $n!$.